# Node.js (node:12276) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I am 
when I am trying to run `nodemon app.js` socioboard-api/user I am getting the following error

```
[nodemon] 1.19.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:1220) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
```

I Used PowerShell and CMD but still having the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is related to socioboard-api/user installation..

you should edit this config [file](https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/search?q=operatorsAliases&unscoped_q=operatorsAliases) and comment the values " "operatorsAliases": false," as per the error `This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed`

as you can see from the error it is a warning only .. which is not going to halt your application, but you need to address it.

Answer (score 2):

From sequelize [docs:](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html)

**Operators Aliases**

Sequelize allows setting specific strings as aliases for operators. **With v5 this will give you deprecation warnin**g.

You should be setting `"operatorsAliases": false` in `config.json` for `v4` and not setting it at all in `v5+` as it will be false by default

Comment: then what should be the approach

Comment: https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/blob/master/socioboard-api/library/sequelize-cli/config/config.json

Comment: version is 5.8.11

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue occur when I was trying to render a table using MySQL. I was able to fix my issue by adding a password into my config.json file. Are you using MySQL or anything of the like that may require you to enter your password?